# Why is my touchpad lagging after closing laptop lid?

Tags: debian, mouse, touchpad, thinkpad

Every time I close the laptop lid, after I re-open it, the touch pad is really sluggish/lagging -- still "works" but is unusable, and is only fixed by a re-boot.

Laptop: Thinkpad t14s
Window manager: wayland

```
$sudo libinput list-devices
...snip...
Device:           SYNA800E:00 06CB:CE67 Touchpad                                                                                                                             
Kernel:           /dev/input/event9                                                                                                                                          
Group:            6                                                                                                                                                          
Seat:             seat0, default                                                                                                                                             
Size:             112x57mm                                                                                                                                                   
Capabilities:     pointer gesture                                                                                                                                            
Tap-to-click:     disabled                                                                                                                                                   
Tap-and-drag:     enabled                                                                                                                                                    
Tap drag lock:    disabled                                                                                                                                                   
Left-handed:      disabled                                                                                                                                                   
Nat.scrolling:    disabled                                                                                                                                                   
Middle emulation: disabled                                                                                                                                                   
Calibration:      n/a                                                                                                                                                        
Scroll methods:   *two-finger edge                                                                                                                                           
Click methods:    *button-areas clickfinger                                                                                                                                  
Disable-w-typing: enabled                                                                                                                                                    
Disable-w-trackpointing: enabled                                                                                                                                             
Accel profiles:   flat *adaptive                                                                                                                                             
Rotation:         n/a

$ uname -a
Linux alpha 6.0.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.0.8-1 (2022-11-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Not sure what other info would be useful. Thank you in advance for any help or direction anyone can provide!

Comment: Within X11, you can use xinput which is very similar to libinput (and probably doesn't require root). It allows to read properties and write them: read them before first suspend, write them back after... I guess the later part could be used along libinput record/replay.

Comment: I'm using wayland not x11 though is the only thing with using xinput

Comment: Change settings to use X11 temporarily so you can record xinput with libinput, then you don't have to anymore. Anyway that's just an idea.